# How to do I make generic types in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I am trying to implement my own find function in TypeScript. There are two parameters in the functions: an array of numbers or objects, and a callback function that returns a number or object or undefined.

This is where I am stuck:

```
type CallBack = (input: number) => boolean;

export function find(array: number[], callback: CallBack) {
  array.forEach((elem) => {
    if (callback(elem)) {
      return elem;
    }
  });
}
```

Here are the test cases:

```
const returnValue1 = find([1, 2, 3], (el) => el === 2);
expect(returnValue1).toEqual(2);

const returnValue2 = find(
  [
    { v: false, id: 1 },
    { v: true, id: 2 },
    { v: true, id: 3 },
  ],
  (el) => el.v
);
expect(returnValue2).toEqual({ v: true, id: 2 });

const returnValue3 = find(
  [
    { v: false, id: 1 },
    { v: false, id: 2 },
    { v: false, id: 3 },
  ],
  (obj) => obj.v
);
expect(returnValue3).toEqual(undefined);
```

I tried creating two generic types, but I am not sure how to encompass all of the different types the array and the function could potentially be.

Comment: Are you just wanting someone to write this code for you? It would help a lot to have an idea of what code have you tried so far. What did and did not work for you?

Comment: Note: you cannot use `.forEach()` for this; you cannot return anything from the callback. You need to use a regular `for` loop.

Comment: This does seem to fail on an easy example like this: `find([1,2,3,4], e => e == 2)`

Answer (score 0):

As Darryl already mentioned, using a regular `for` loop does solve the issue.
Here's the modified code:

```js
function find(array, callback) {
  /*array.forEach((elem) => {
    if (callback(elem)) {
      return elem;
    }
  });*/
  
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (callback(array[i])) {
        return array[i];
    }
  }
}
```

This is because the `return` in `forEach` returns from `forEach`, and not from `find`

I've ran the tests and this does work

Comment: Note: you could also use `for-of` in this case, if you wanted.